# Jmeter: Access all results from all threadGroups from JSR223 Sampler or BeanShell Sampler in TeardownThread

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, benchmarking, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

is there a way to get info about all requests in the mentioned samplers after main thread group finished? In TeardownThread maybe?
I want to perform some calculation and send couple request which are based on info about those requests and it is to resource consuming to do it with sampler for each of the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The options are in:

1. Parse the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)
2. Use the [JSR23 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) in the main Thread Group. The Listeners obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) if you don't want your code to run after all samplers
3. Create a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html), the most suitable option for your case would be your own implementation of [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener)